# Push property and value at the specif position in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My data looks like this.

```
var data = [{
  "ID": 1,
  "bankRepaidAmt": "",
  "Tasks": [{
    ID: 5,
    "chainPrefix": "1C",
    "book": "Canada CRU",
  }, ]
}]
```

Now, I am trying to add a property 'bookedDate' with value '13/1/17' under 'Tasks'. I tried with below syntax. But it throws error. Can anybody help.

```
data
  .find(record => record.ID == '1')
  .Tasks
  .find(task => task.ID == '5')
  .push({'bookedDate': '13/1/17'});
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by *under 'Tasks*?

Comment: @torazaburo: Property push does not exist on type Task.

Comment: Possibly that `push` isn't a method of Object, because `find(task => task.ID == '1')` returns an Object not an Array.

Comment: @rajesh: Along with properties ID, chainPrefix and Book, i want to add bookedDate with value.

Comment: As _under 'Tasks'_ you mean another property **in** the `Tasks`, or next property **after** `Tasks`?

Comment: @cyrix: Can you please provide correct syntax to push the property if my syntax is wrong

Comment: Look at the answers. It's already there.

Comment: @debute: Yes. I want to add another property in Tasks.

Comment: All you need to do is `.find(x=>x.id === 5)["bookDate"] = value`.  But remember, `array.find` will return `null` if no match is found and in that case, your code will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var data = [{
    "ID"                  : 1,
    "bankRepaidAmt"       : "",
    "Tasks"     : [{
                    ID                : 5,
                    "chainPrefix"     : "1C",
                    "book"            : "Canada CRU",
                    },
                     ]
    }];
    
  var x =  data.find(record => record.ID == '1').Tasks.find(task => task.ID == '5').bookedDate = '13/1/17';
  console.log(data);
```

Comment: What have you  changed and why will this solve the issue? Just putting working code is not enough.  Please explain changes as well. You are answering for readers and not just OP

Answer (score 1):

You return object so you can use `Object.assign()` to add new property. Also you can first check if object is found and then add property.

```js
 var data = [{
   "ID": 1,
   "bankRepaidAmt": "",
   "Tasks": [{
     ID: 5,
     "chainPrefix": "1C",
     "book": "Canada CRU",
   }]
 }]

var obj = data.find(record => record.ID == '1').Tasks.find(task => task.ID == '5')
if(obj) Object.assign(obj, {'bookedDate': '13/1/17'})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *push* as you are trying to add a *property* to an object I guess -  use this:

```
data.find(record => record.ID == '1').Tasks.find(task => task.ID == '5')['bookedDate'] = '13/1/17';
```

See demo below:

```js
var data = [{
  "ID": 1,
  "bankRepaidAmt": "",
  "Tasks": [{
    ID: 5,
    "chainPrefix": "1C",
    "book": "Canada CRU",
  }, ]
}]

data.find(record => record.ID == '1').Tasks.find(task => task.ID == '5')['bookedDate'] = '13/1/17';

console.log(data);
```